# How to parse email body from outlook in python dataframe

Tags: python, email, outlook, html-email, pywin32

My objective is to parse email body from outlook and store it in pandas dataframe thenusing regex get specific values from that dataframe and insert it using oracle database. i am done with regex and oracle script but not able to add outlook emails as dataframe. Can anyone please correct me ? Below is the script

```
import win32com.client
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pprint import pprint
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

outlook = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Outlook.Application")
mapi = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = mapi.Folders['rahul.vaidya@xyz.com'].Folders['Inbox'].Folders['Important']
Mail_Messages = inbox.Items
Mail_Messages = Mail_Messages.Restrict("[Subject] = 'SGPSBSH Index Level*'")
received_dt = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)

for mail in Mail_Messages:
    receivedtime = mail.ReceivedTime.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    body = mail.HTMLBody
    html_body = BeautifulSoup(body, "lxml")
   print(Mail_Messages.body)
```

SAMPLE EMAIL

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I've noticed the following line of code:

```
inbox = mapi.Folders['rahul.vaidya@xyz.com'].Folders['Inbox'].Folders['Important']
```

Use the [NameSpace.GetDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.inspector.wordeditor) method which returns a Folder object that represents the default folder of the requested type for the current profile; for example, obtains the default `Inbox` folder for the user who is currently logged on.

If you need to get the Inbox folder for a specific store in Outlook you may consider using the [Store.GetDefaultFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-htmlbody-property-outlook) method instead. This method is similar to the `GetDefaultFolder` method of the `NameSpace` object. The difference is that this method gets the default folder on the delivery store that is associated with the account, whereas `NameSpace.GetDefaultFolder` returns the default folder on the default store for the current profile.

The Outlook object model supports three main ways of dealing with the message bodies:

1. The [Body](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-body-property-outlook) property returns or sets a string representing the clear-text body of the Outlook item.
2. The [HTMLBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-htmlbody-property-outlook) property of the `MailItem` class returns or sets a string representing the HTML body of the specified item. Setting the `HTMLBody` property will always update the `Body` property immediately. For example:

   ```
    Sub CreateHTMLMail() 
      'Creates a new e-mail item and modifies its properties. 
      Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem 
      'Create e-mail item 
      Set objMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem) 
      With objMail 
       'Set body format to HTML 
       .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML 
       .HTMLBody = "<HTML><BODY>Enter the message <a href="http://google.com">text</a> here. </BODY></HTML>" 
       .Display 
      End With 
    End Sub
   ```
3. The Word object model can be used for dealing with message bodies. See [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012(v=office.12).aspx) for more information.

It is up to you which way is to choose.

Comment: i am able to print the email body now looking to get specific values using regex